# Python: Add dynamic text in Matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made an animation from the list of images saved as numpy arrays.
Then I want to add a text onto the animation like like a subtitle whose text changes for each frame but placing `plt.text(some_string)` only adds the string at the first iteration and it does not work if I change the passed string in the loop. Below is my attempt. Please note HTML is just for Jupyter Lab.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

folderName = "hogehoge"
picList = glob.glob(folderName + "\*.npy")

fig = plt.figure()
ims = []
 
for i in range(len(picList)):
    plt.text(10, 10, i) # This does not add the text properly
    tmp = Image.fromarray(np.load(picList[i]))
    ims.append(plt.imshow(tmp))     
 
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=200)
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have also to add the text object to the list of artists for each frame:

```py
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ims = []
for i in range(10):
    artists = ax.plot(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10))
    text = ax.text(x=0.5, y=0.5, s=i)
    artists.append(text)
    ims.append(artists)
    
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=200)
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```